# Whats the meaning of this syntax

Tags: typescript

whats the meaning of `const DISHES: Dish[]` and `dishes: dish[] = DISHES;`
Does the cases matter ?
Why cant we just do `const Dish[]=[{id: '0'}]` and why `dishes: dish[] = DISHES;` didn't require  var or const.

```
const DISHES: Dish[] = [
      {
        id: '0',
        name: 'Uthappizza',
        image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        featured: true,
        label: 'Hot',
        price: '4.99',
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.'
      }
     ];

    export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
      dishes: Dish[] = DISHES;
      //or dishes = DISHES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`const DISHES: Dish[] = [...]` defines the `DISHES` array with items of type `Dish`.

The other part in `MenuComponent` is defining class property `dishes`, again with items of type `Dish`, and initialising it with value `DISHES` (with same type).

> Why cant we just do const Dish[]=[{id: '0'}]

`const Dish[]=[{id: '0'}]` is not valid TS syntax - you are missing the property name. `Dish` is just the type.

> why dishes: dish[] = DISHES; didn't require var or const.

Because `dishes` is class property of `MenuComponent`.

Comment: Thanks can you tell whats the use of class property `dishes` because in the .html file it was fetched using `dish.image` and `dish.name` Is it just for the sake of the syntax.

Comment: Take a look here for more info about ES6 classes (TS just adds typing, but it sounds like you are looking for more general info): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

`const DISHES: Dish[]` defined the type of DISHES (Array of items which have type Dish)
`dishes: dish[] = DISHES` does the same thing, even that type definition here is not really necessary, as `= DISHES` already did that so `dishes = DISHES` is just enough.

`const Dish[]=[{id: '0'}]` is not valid syntax, as I understand in your code Dish refers to a type, not a value

`dishes: dish[] = DISHES;` doesn't require var or const as it is a property of the `MenuComponent` class, not a variable

Answer (score 0):

> varname : type = VALUE;

- So in your case: Dish[] is an array of Dish type.
- The case matters Dish[] and dish[] are different underlying objects.
- No need for var or const in `dishes: Dish[] = DISHES;` as this is a member variable. Use let or var for local ones.